# scanf in while loop > 1

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
/**********************
Read in numbers and add only the positive one.
Quit when input is 0.
***********************/
int main()
{
    float num,sum = 0.0 ;

    while(scanf("%f",&num) > 0)
    {
        if (num == 0)
            break;

        else if (num > 0)
            sum += num;

    }
    printf("sum = %f\n",sum);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm confused as to why this code work normally until I changed this line
`while(scanf("%f",&num) > 0 )`
to
`while(scanf("%f",&num) > 1 )` or 2,3,4,5,...... ( it's not working )
but when I changed it to
`while(scanf("%f",&num) > -1 )` or -2,-3,-4,-5,....
it works perfectly

Comment: Your scanf will return one of `1`, `0`, `EOF`. It returns `1` when ok; it returns `0` when input is, for example, `"foo"`, it returns `EOF` when there is no data available or some kind of hardware error or some other error... A "longer" scanf will return `EOF` and `0` and `1` like before... can return `2`, `3`, ... up to the number of assignments made. (`while (scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4)`)

Comment: How do I do it to make it recieve only >1 ? to get in the loop

Comment: Why do you want to change it to `> 1`?  What do you expect that to do?

Comment: If you want scanf to return 2 or more you need 2 or more assignments: `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)` yields `EOF`, `0`, `1`, or `2` ... `scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c)` yields `EOF`, `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` ...

Comment: Oh Sorry! I just learned about this today so I kinda confused a bit and thought `while(scanf("%f",&num) > 1 )` mean it would only go in loop only if it recieve number > 1

Comment: now I have more question.  what's the difference between `while(scanf("%f",&num) ==1 )` and `while(scanf("%f",&num) > 0 )` ? because both seem to work.

Comment: In your case, no difference.  You should have a look at the manual page for scanf: <https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html>.  Especially at the RETURN VALUE section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check inside the while loop doesn't detect that value which you've provided (n). It reads a float and puts it inside n. Then the return value of scanf is not the value it reads from user input but the number of values read, which in your case are 1. That's why when you change it to 2 it won't work.